# Go: regexp matching a pattern AND then another pattern

Tags: regex, go

I have the following Golang code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    // dummy text data
    blob := `
    #s-kiwi
    foo
    #e-kiwi
    #s-banana
        bar
    #e-banana
    #s-mango
    baz
    #e-mango
    `

    // try to match two lines
    fruit := "banana"
    result, _ := regexp.MatchString("#[se]-"+fruit, blob)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Go playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/p9Q4HYijx9m

I am trying to achieve a full matching with the usage of an AND property. I would like to search for, the pattern `#s-banana` AND `#e-banana` just to ensure that the blob text has its enclosing and initiator parameters.

What I have tried is using `regexp.MatchString("#[se]-"+fruit, blob)` but `"#[se]-"` only matches characters `s` OR `e`.

Could this be implemented in a oneliner? Should I add a new regexp condition? If that's the case this does not seem quite polished.

What my desired result is:

Trying to search for two strings in text with regexp on golang using an AND condition.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you are trying to do.  But assuming you want to confirm the multiline text contains a pair of tags starting with `#s-banana` and ending with `#e-banana` you can search for that, with any number of characters inbetween:

```golang
result, _ := regexp.MatchString("(?s)#s-"+fruit+".*?#e-"+fruit, blob)
```

That returns `true`.  The initial `(?s)` allows `.` to match newlines too, and the `.*?` matches the shortest sequence of zero or more characters including newlines.

Comment: Thanks! I used your answer and added some extra things in order to just "grep" for the exact match:

``result, _ := regexp.MatchString("(?s)#s-"+fruit+"\\b.*?#e-"+fruit+"\\b", blob)``

Comment: Good point about the `\b` after `fruit`, so that `banana` doesn't match `bananas`.

Comment: Modified even more to be super exactly precise, if using ``\b`` char ``-`` does not count as boundarie. The following code is an even a better exact matcher:
``result, _ := regexp.MatchString("(?sm)#s-"+fruit+"$.*?#e-"+fruit+"$", blob)``